# php tags not working. what is diference between php tags <php and <?

Tags: php, html

First code is fine but textfield give back all php tag

```
<td><?php print($code_verification);?>
    <input type="text" name="packaging_code" id="packaging_code" value="<?=$code_verification?>" />
```

Comment: **A:** => [`Open short tags are not on`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) either set them on, or change `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
value="<?=$code_verification?>"
```

to:

```
value="<?php echo $code_verification; ?>"
```

The first line would work if your server had [short_open_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled.

Comment: Code "to change" should work.

Answer (score 0):

your first code will work if you enable short tags.otherwise you can try below code

```
  <input type="text" name="packaging_code" id="packaging_code" value="<?php echo $code_verification; ?>" />
```